# Ignore foreach afterAdd and beforeRemove in certain situations

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an array of users that I get via Ajax when the page loads and I list them using the `foreach` binding, like this:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: usersArr, 
                           afterAdd: showElement, 
                           beforeRemove: fadeRemove }">
```

I want the list to show up on page load *without* the `fadeIn()` effect I apply to it using `afterAdd` and to disappear when I empty the `usersArr` array, without `beforeRemove` firing.

I only want the effects to fire when adding a new user or deleting an existing one.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you push the elements one by one at load time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load all your data at once in your `userArr` instead of pushing them one by one:

```
viewmodel.userArr(receivedArray); //instead of viewmodel.userArr.push(newElement)
```

### EDIT

The above does not work. The `afterAdd` and `beforeRemove` bindings do not care how the elements are added/removed, they will be called in any case.

Here is an ugly trick: add a `allowAnimation` variable to your viewmodel and run the code only when it is set (told you it's ugly):

```
ViewModel.prototype.showElement = function(elem, index, user) {
    if (user.allowAnimation) {
        if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
            $(elem).hide().fadeIn();
            user.allowAnimation = false;
        }
    }
};

ViewModel.prototype.fadeRemove = function(elem, index, user) {
    if (user.allowAnimation) {
        if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).fadeOut(500, function() {             
            $(elem).remove(); 
            user.allowAnimation = false;
        });
    } else {
        $(elem).remove();
    }
};

ViewModel.prototype.addUser = function() {
    this.usersArr.push({name: 'bla', allowAnimation: true});
};

ViewModel.prototype.removeUser = function(user) {
    user.allowAnimation = true;
    this.usersArr.remove(user);
};
```

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/LqGXL/5/)**

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to make any difference, although I think it does help with performance, so I will look into that later. Here's a fiddle to better illustrate the problem I'm having: http://jsfiddle.net/norbiu/LqGXL/ - try clicking on the "Load All at Once" button at the top multiple times. That's what happens when I'm switching between user pages. I clear out the old data to bring in a new userArr.

Comment: @Norbert it's always easier with an example. Updated answer. This should work, not very beautiful though :( Another option was to add the animation on the `click` event of the buttons instead of the `foreach` binding. Works great for the remove. But it's another story when it comes to adding